# IRegionNavigationService is truly not a replacement for Frame-and-Page-based Navigation?

Tags: wpf, xaml, prism, mef

In “[8: Navigation Using the Prism Library 5.0 for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861(v=PandP.40).aspx)” we all see that:

> …the Prism region navigation was not designed to replace WPF's
>   navigation framework. Instead, Prism region navigation was designed to
>   be used side-by-side with the WPF navigation framework.

However, I find it quite difficult to find an example of this (especially when MEF is used). The example I want to see declares a Prism Region in XAML like this:

```
<Frame prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static myShared:RegionNames.MyRegion}" />
```

When I call `RequestNavigate()` *twice* for a `Frame`-based Region (requesting the same URI) the navigation only happens *once* in a sequence like this:

- Load Index page in `MyRegion`
- `RequestNavigate()` to Page X from Index page (*navigation will succeed*)
- Hit back button (from default `Frame` chrome) to load Index again
- `RequestNavigate()` to Page X from Index page (*navigation will fail*)

What this experience is telling me that, yes, it is possible to use Frame-and-Page-based Navigation side by side with Prism *but you cannot use them together*. Would this assertion be in the ball park?